# Tkinter won't accurately reflect kwargs when making a new frame. How do I change inheriting frame background color?

Tags: python, tkinter

In my code, I'm creating an object called a `HistoryFrame` that is supposed to inherit from `tkinter.Frame`. I want to change the background color of my `HistoryFrame` as a parameter that's passed in on its creation, and when I print kwargs, it accurately reflects a that I've passed in {'bg':'blue', etc...}, but it doesn't change the actual color of the background of the frame.

How do I fix this? and why is this happening?

[Picture of Application resulting from code below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoNmY.png)
Code below. V---V

```
import tkinter as tk

class HistoryFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs)
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        button = tk.Button(self, text="hello", fg="blue")
        button.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)



class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        self.width, self.height = max(parent.winfo_screenwidth(), 200), max(
            parent.winfo_screenheight(), 200
        )

        self.history_frame = HistoryFrame.HistoryFrame(
            self, width=max(20, self.width // 4), height=self.height, bg="blue"
        )
        self.history_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.X)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("650x250")
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Calling `pack()` on the button inside `HistoryFrame` will shrink the size of the frame to the size of the button.

Comment: I see; thank you. I have to find a way to organize my button into the center of the frame without using pack. How would I do that? @acw1668. For some reason, ```button.grid``` also fails me, and shrinks the ```Frame``` onto the button

Comment: You can use `place()`.

Comment: `place` is very rarely the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your color is working fine. By default, when you add one or more widgets to a frame with `pack` or `grid`, the frame will shrink to fit its children. The color is there, it's just that the frame is hidden by the button.

You can observe this by changing how you pack the frame:

```
self.history_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill="both", expand=True)
```

[image: screenshot]